# system verilog expect behavior

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

I tried using expect with the following property

```
module tb;

logic a;
logic clk=0;

default clocking @(posedge clk); endclocking

always
  #5ns clk = ~clk;

initial begin
  $dumpfile("dump.vcd"); $dumpvars;
  $display("START");
  a = 0;
  #100ns;
  a = 1;
  #100ns;
  $finish;
end

initial begin
  #10ns;
  expect(@(posedge clk) 1 ##1 $changed(a) |-> 1) $display("SUCCESS"); else
$display("FAIL");
end

endmodule
```

Is the expect going to block until a change from 0 to 1 at 100ns ?

Comment: did it even compile for you?

Comment: With the tool I'm using (irun) you need to define default clocking block in order to compile it. I don't know for the other tools

Comment: It also doesn't compile for me. Can you please share your actual code? I have also tries with default clocking block

Comment: You can use the following eda link : https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2nvM

Answer (score 0):

No, it will block until the second `(posedge clk)`, regardless of the value of `a`, and will always pass.

The `expect` statement does not start evaluating the property until the first clk edge. The antecedent takes two cycle to either match or not match. Since the consequent is always true, the property passes on match. If there is no match, the property also passes, vacuously.

Comment: As i understood expect is blocking until the antecedent part of the property matches, which is my case takes 100ns. That s a bit confusing for me.

If I write the following, it matches my expected behavior : 
expect(@ (posedge clk) ##[1:$] $changed(a))

Comment: You never showed how your clk is specified, If the period was 50ns, then it was a coincidence that `a` changed at the same time as the second `clk` posedge

Comment: Hi Dave, sorry for the confusion. I updated the code in the first message.
So I would expect the message SUCCESS to be printed at 200+5ns but neither SUCCESS neither FAIL is printed during the simulation.